# Can I post a blog entry in a user's name?

Tags: nodes

I just found a new user has posted a dozen or so "blog entries" which were actually all posted as comments to a single forum question

I have explained to the user who will - hopefully - "add content" / "type = blog" in future.

Ideally, I would like to somehow edit those user comments and change them into user blog posts. Can I do that?

If not, I can copy /paste them; but can I create a new blog post entry in the user's name? And can I change its time-stamp to agree with the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If not, I can copy /paste them; but can I create a new blog post entry in the user's name? And can I change its time-stamp to agree with the original?

In Drupal 6, the users with the permission of administer nodes can set the author of a node they are creating, using the following field set:

[image: screenshot]

It is possible to change the author of a node already existing, and a node that is being created.

The same is true for Drupal 7.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and paste the comments into new nodes where the type is "blog".  If you have adequate permissions, you can change the author on the node edit form.  It is in the "Authoring information" in the set of vertical tabs at the bottom of the form.